# How to install previous version of Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node.js. The project i will be working on use 4.2.6 version. Im not sure How do i install this version on my local machine ( its Windows 10 64 bit). I tried browsing to previous versions [here](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v4.2.6/) but there is no installer there.

The current Windows Installer on Nodejs.org in 4.3.1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The installer is there, it's named [`node-v4.2.6-x64.msi`](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v4.2.6/node-v4.2.6-x64.msi).

Answer (score -1):

You can use node version management. For example, [marcelklehr/nodist](https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist):

```
> nodist + v4.2.6
# Just checks, if the version is installed and downloads it if not.
```